# How can I change the Print Spooler filename/document name associated with wxPrintout in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, visual-c++, printing, wxwidgets, print-spooler-api

I have managed to attach my filename to my print out by overloading the wxPrintout constructor with my chosen name.

```
 wxPrintout(const wxString& title = wxT("Printout"));
```

In my code:

```
VRPrintout::VRPrintout(blababala):wxPrintout(_("Heartrate")),
```

But on printing to save as a PDF, in the filename dialog, it reads "Printing Heartrate".

**How can I get rid of "Printing" added before the name or even change it?**

Comment: I know nothing about wxwidgets, but if it supports calls into the Win32 API there is quite likely a solution.

Comment: So have you abandoned this question?

Comment: Actually I have found a solution from the wxWidgets forum, will post it here now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Credits to Xaviou from wxDev.fr.**

You can try overriding the "OnBeginDocument" method in your wxPrintout derived class.

The default code is the following (the "OnBeginDocument" is virtual) in wx-src/common/prntbase.cpp:584 :

```
 bool wxPrintout::OnBeginDocument(int WXUNUSED(startPage), int WXUNUSED(endPage))
{
   return GetDC()->StartDoc(_("Printing ") + m_printoutTitle);
}
```

I think that if you provide yours with the correct text, it should be ok.

Regards
Xav'

Edit : Tested on an app of mine that do printing stuff, and it works...

**Worked for me too**